# Given a Stripe payment intent ID, how can I find the checkout session ID?

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-payments-js

For a successful payment, how can I find the related checkout session ID given the payment intent ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case you would just use the [Checkout Session List API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/list#list_checkout_sessions-payment_intent) and pass in the Payment Intent ID for the `payment_intent` parameter.  That will return an array with the related Checkout Session in it.

Answer (score 0):

Given a Stripe payment intent ID, you can find the checkout session ID like so:

## From Stripe CLI

```bash
stripe checkout sessions list --payment-intent=pi_abc --limit=1 --expand=data.line_items
```

## Line items

Taking it a step further, this PHP example will return the line items for a given payment intent:

```php
/**
 * Returns an array of line items. On each, can access properties `price`,
 * `quantity` and more. e.g.:
 * - getLinesItemsFromPaymentIntent('pi_3MCJzWBkWO5ojRjq1zBX6gA3')[0]->price->id
 * - getLinesItemsFromPaymentIntent('pi_3MCJzWBkWO5ojRjq1zBX6gA3')[0]->quantity
 */
function getLinesItemsFromPaymentIntent($payment_intent_id) {
    $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(
        getenv('STRIPE_API_SECRET_KEY')
    );

    // https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/list?lang=cli#list_checkout_sessions-payment_intent
    $session = $stripe->checkout->sessions->all([
        'limit' => 1,
        'payment_intent' => $payment_intent_id,
        'expand' => ['data.line_items'],
    ]);

    return $session->data[0]->line_items->data ?? false;
}
```

## Limitations

In passing, note that **this will only work with products ordered through a Stripe Payment Link AKA Stripe-hosted payment page AKA `checkout sessions`** in the API.

If/when using your own payment form, you will need to use yet another approach to retrieve line items / what was ordered by your customer

Ergo, the way to make things more consistent when using multiple types of order forms is to set/read metadata on the Subscription, payment_intent_data or whatever handles your orders.